# How could I cast a type stored in a string to a type at runtime on dlang?

Tags: casting, d

I want to deserialize a variable and for that I have stored its type in a string just like this:

```
int var = 60;
auto type = typeid(int).toString;
writeln(type); //Prints "int"
```

But now, when I have to deserialize it, I can not just cast the string to a real type as it is required to do it at compile time. I could make a table and store alias to types or build a big switch block for every type, but it will eventually get really annoying. Does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: What are you trying to do with it? There are solutions for this kind of thing, but they are kind of specific. For example if you want to fill a class/struct member with its value, saving its member name instead of the type is better, CTFE can then iterate all members and set it where the name matches.

Comment: It could be interesting to have a method that returns the type that TypeInfo refers to. I need it to deserialize any type of variable. I have a template that converts every type (doesn't matter if it is an array) to an array of unsigned bytes and then I want to write it into a binary file. Every data should be stored with the type of variable it's needed to be written to later. But then I can't simply restore the data to the targeted type without a kind of previous index, because it can't be done at runtime.

Comment: What you are asking for is not possible, you can't return a type based on runtime information. And yeah, it's pretty clear how serializing works. You haven't answered my question though, what would you do with that type? To deserialize it into, sure, but what then? Are you passing the object to a function? Setting a variable, named based on the type?

Comment: This problem has been solved already: https://wiki.dlang.org/Serialization_Libraries